# Calling multiple std=cXX in C makefile

Tags: c, compilation, std

I was wondering what happens if you call multiple std=cXX? I tried it in my code and nothing outward happened on compile so I didnt know if it worked or not.

```
-std=c99 -std=c11 -std=c1x
```

What happens? Does it use all 3 `std` or is the last one that called?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most gcc flags follow a model that the *last* conflicting option on the line is the one that is actually in force. For example, using `-O -O1 -O2 -O3` really means the same as `-O3`.

Comment: so if -03 conflicts the -02 gets called? I'm guessing that any code that relies on -03 will break?

Comment: No, I mean since `-O3` is the last option, so it's the only one that matters.